# Submit form button does not work on WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

When loading some websites in a WebView, I am not able to submit their forms. When clicking the submit input (button), it gets focused, but nothing else happens.

Those same sites work on Chrome (in the same device).

**How can I fix this?** Is there a setting I am missing?

**Feedback on why this issue happens will be appreciated, too.**

### Example

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Load **BrowseActivity**, which will load `https://m.ebay.com/`
2. Once the page loads, enter a search query (e.g. "Laptop")
3. Press the form's blue search button or the action button of the software keyboard (magnifier glass icon)

**Expected behavior**: The search form should be submitted and the search results shown

**Actual behaviour**: The blue search button gets focus (represented by a bright border), but nothing else happens.

**BrowseActivity.java**

```
public class BrowseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.home_wv_content);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Ebay has a blue search button where this issue can be replicated
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://m.ebay.com");
    }
}
```

**activity_browse.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.example.BrowseActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/home_wv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit:**

I have considered using a custom [JavaScript interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) in order to catch the click on the button, read the input query and then redirect to the search page.

Anyway, this approach is tightly coupled to the website itself (e.g. ebay) and I'd like this to work with different sites. Also, I don't want changes in the website to break my application.

Comment: Maybe a suggestion instead of loading those website in your webview. Let them load in browers app instead?

Comment: @Steven, unfortunately, I'm unable to do that, since my application needs to parse data from the webview which depends on the user's interaction with the website being shown.

Comment: sometimes things don't work in android webview. I can't help you. Maybe on suggestion couldn't use an api of Ebay instead?

Comment: Ebay was just an example, I need to load different websites in my app.

Comment: Did you debuged when you pressed the blue button? Because I did and I am getting warnings because. So do you have that to?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you disable JavaScript in your sample app, the search button on m.ebay.com will work. (Just tried it.) My guess is that there is a JavaScript error or some other JS interaction that is causing a silent failure.

Comment: @Cheticamp I have tried it my self and your are getting a JS error something is undefined.

Comment: have you logged requests ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may need to enable other things in webview to have full equivalent of a browser. There are other things that are disabled by default in webview in addition to javascript).

Try this setting (based on my project where we did have some problems with webview):

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(dbpath); //check the documentation for info about dbpath
mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! `mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` and `mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);` did it as the problem was that ebay (and some other sites) use LocalStorage and that resulted in a JS error since when those options are not enabled, `localStorage` is null

Comment: Same problem for me, but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: `mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` and `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` were right for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues one in particular is to upload a file.

**Feedback on why this issue happens:-**

The issue is that there are different OS Version and different Web Engine Versions. Since I would assume the web view is presenting a HTML5 page and it doesn't work well on that given device, you would probably need more than JS enabled.

Some webpages keep track on the number of submits and they need access to client/web storage.

```
WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Done above
mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Try
mWebSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
```

I can't help much without knowing at-least the Android OS version which will point to the Web engine version used.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set JavaScriptEnabled true like below:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```