# Access remote pdf file with login (authentication)

Tags: android, webview, moodle

I am facing problem with `loading URL` in `web-view`. `Web-view` shows blank because it is not logged in. How to access `course file` without login into moodle2.6 by using `url`.

**Using this url format**

http://example.com/pluginfile.php/4418/mod_resource/content/10/xx-t2.pdf

**Here is my web-view code**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //progDailog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            //progDailog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/pluginfile.php/4418/mod_resource/content/10/xx-t2.pdf");
```

Comment: Would you like to download the file or access it via webview(PDF)

Comment: Yes. I want to show PDF in webview

Comment: is it possible to share the exact link you're trying to access via the webview

Comment: Yes. I will provide you

Comment: lms.jsbl.com//pluginfile.php//4925//mod_resource//content//0//calendar_cal_605.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the pdf URL to Google Doc Viewer to open pdf in web view, Also you will need to enable `JavaScript` for your `webview`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webview;
    String pageURL = "https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html";
    String pdf = "http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf"; //your pdf address

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                //progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                //progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //webview.loadUrl(pageURL);
        webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf); //simply append pdf address to doc viewer
    }
}
```

> Sample PDF opened in webview

[image]

Comment: Not working. I need to load Moodle pdf not simple pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're webclient is not calling their super methods, which could be one reason for the page to not load, use the following code to load the login page, which once signed in the user could view the intended pdf file.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);//<-- this is important when overriding
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);//<-- this is important when overriding

        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://lms.jsbl.com//pluginfile.php//4925//mod_resource//content//0//calendar_cal_605.pdf");
```

And also If you want you view a pdf using the webview you need append the following before your url so that the google plugin could be used to load the pdf 
    https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=

(for this to work make sure you have added the following to your webview
 `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);`)

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46125288/4944007) some login form submit might not work on android webview so set all/some(check if your login works without it) on your webview to make the login work

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(dbpath); //check the documentation for info about dbpath
mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
```

**But if you know the credentials for the login You could [follow the instruction on this](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/08/android-webview-fill-form-and-submit.html) site to inject a javascript to the webview which would fire the Login form submit on the webview and redirect to the pdf file directly**

**UPDATE 16/3/2018**

Use the following code which will append the google pdf widget during a redirect 
and has a pdf extension

```
boolean isInititialRedirectComplete = false;
boolean isPdfRedirectComplete  = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    f-inal WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.testWebView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                           if (url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".")).equalsIgnoreCase(".pdf") && !isPdfRedirectComplete && isInititialRedirectComplete ){
                isPdfRedirectComplete = true;
                webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
            }
            isInititialRedirectComplete = true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(
            "https://lms.jsbl.com//pluginfile.php//4925//mod_resource//content//0//calendar_cal_605.pdf");

}
```

Comment: Not Working!! Web view shows the html script. here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/MooqDrc

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of the currrently changed code and let me know

Comment: Sure. I have create a gist please have a look https://gist.github.com/Fazalcs13/c4df1afd08a70c7f45f5d41ce0cfc479

Comment: One more clarification, are you going to allow the user to sign into to site using the webview and show the pdf or do you have the sign in credentials and you want the user to directly show the pdf by auto signing in

Comment: URL check if the user logged in so it will show the PDF otherwise show the login page. I have already sign in i want to show PDF file.

Comment: I tried with this google search link, which loaded a list of pdf results and clicking on a pdf link did the job https://www.google.lk/search?q=sample+pdf&oq=sample+pdf&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.2212j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166860/discussion-between-fazal-hussain-and-ismail-iqbal).

Comment: Can you try the **UPDATE 16/3/2018** and let us know

Comment: Yes. It's keep on showing html script instead of pdf